# What is the correct way to define models and their validation?

Tags: validation, aurelia

I want to create a supplier model i.e code, name, address, phone

I am also going to use the aurelia-validation classes.

Using them both together with the viewmodel - SupplierMaint.js & view - SupplierMaint.html is fine but I want to keep the Supplier model in another file so that I can use it in many places to ensure a consistent validation of values lengths etc.

How should I go about this?

I suspect the @NoView annotation might have something to do with it but I am not sure how to import the external file and wire it up to the submit & validation processing in the SupplierMaint.js

Bob

Answer (score 1):

### Models

This is how I do it -

```
export class Supplier {
  name = '';
  modelId = '';
  constructor(data) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}
```

This let's anyone consume your model and create a new instance of it.  The data that is passed in will override the default values you define, but if they do not you still have those default values.

### Validation

Validation is currently in a state of flux.  I'm hoping to be done with the initial refactoring work by the end of this weekend but here is a preview for what I propose as the best usage, feedback welcome.

```
import {ValidationReporter} from 'aurelia-validate';

export class PersonViewModel {
  activePerson;
  static inject = [ValidationReporter];
  constructor(reporter) {
    this.activePerson = new PersonModel({firstName: 'Lucky Luke'});
    this.reporter = reporter.subscribe(validationErrors => {
      // do something with validationErrors
    });
  }
}

class PersonModel {
  @length({ minimum: 5, maximum: 25 }) firstName = 'Luke';
  @required lastName = 'Skywalker';
  @date lastUpdated = new Date();
  @datetime lastTimeUpdated = new Date();
  @email email = 'luke@skywalker.net';
  @length({ minimum: 5, maximum: 25 }) password = 'equal';
  @equality confirmPassword = 'equal';
  @url website = 'http://www.google.com';
  @numericality friendCount = 25;
  @numericality({ noStrings: true }) age = 25;
  constructor(data) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
}
```